# Creating a interactive avatar selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Similar to how XBOX LIVE or PSN allows users to select an image/avatar from their database, how would I be able to achieve the same result using Javascript/jQuery, I used PHP to achieve this functionality, however, for further learning, I'd like to explore how this functionality could be achieved through other means (js or jQuery), my PHP code is down below:

```
<?php

    $imageFile = "../img/avatars/";
    $imageLoop = glob($imageFile. '*.*' , GLOB_BRACE);

    foreach($imageLoop as $image){
        echo "<label id='avatarLabel'><input type='radio' class='avatarInput' name='avatar' value='$image' >
        <img src='$image' id='avatarImage'></label>";
    }
    ?>
?>
```

my JQuery attempt at displaying images from folder:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
("body").load("imgs/");
)}
```

Comment: Whats this code for `for($x=0; $x<=130; $x++){
   }`

Comment: @RiggsFolly it was meant to give each image an individual value, and it was meant as a way to make sure each radio button would be treated like a radio button as without, you can select multiple radio buttons...

Comment: What do you mean by "limit the folder"?

Comment: @Qirel I mean can I force the users to be only able to select images from a folder I already created with images I already put in

Comment: And how isn't the code you have right now already working? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Qirel it doesnt take into account the path of the image, as it assumes that all the images are just one huge file...

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There is NO way to do it using php. Php can only process the file from POST data ad it will be located in a temp directory. At that moment there will be no data about original file folder.

Might be there are ways to do it using javascript, but it will be safety violation...

Comment: So even I make a folder, have all the images imported, I cannot make it so that the pictures can only be selected from that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, if I understand it correctly:

```
<?php

$dir = '../img/avatar/';

$loop = GLOB($dir. '*{.jpg,.png}', GLOB_BRACE); // look for only jpg and png

foreach ($loop as $image) {
    $filename = basename($image); // only file name without path
    echo '<input type="radio" name="avatar_register" value="' . $filename . '" required><img src="' . $image . '">';
}

?>
```

The numeric value of $x doesn't have any meaning and I have changed to $filename so you can locate the image with
$dir . $_POST['avatar_register'];

Since you are just selecting existing images from folder, no upload process is needed. You simply need to know which image user has picked.

I also have removed the id="" as it's inside a loop. Which means multiple ids with same value will be generated. This may cause some future problem if you are trying to locate the id from DOM